# How to define a two-dimensional rectangular array in JSON Schema?

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema

How to define the two-dimensional array in JSON schema? The problem is that I know, how to define a 2D array with exact items count in a row:

```json
{
    type: "array",
    items: {
        type: "array",
        items: {
            type: "number",
            minItems: 2,
            maxItems: 2
        }
    },
}
```

But I cannot understand, how to define an array that has exactly the same number of items in each row when this number is not fixed. In other words, I need to define a rectangular shape of a 2D array.

This data should be valid:

```json
[
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
]
```

and this data also should be valid:

```json
[
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
]
```

This shouldn't:

```json
[
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2, 3],
]
```

and this shouldn't:

```json
[
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
]
```

Comment: Is there a max size of square matrix that can be sent? If so then you can describe it with brute force oneOf descriptions for every size.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible with JSON Schema because you can't provide dynamic values relating to the instance JSON to the JSON Schema.